# Add two buttons on the right in list header

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I try to make the two `<a </a>` elements into the header on the right side into the same row how `<?php echo $row['date']; ?>` become showed. Now the buttons are only among themselves and under the date row. How can I fix it, that they are into the same row how the date?

```
<li id ="listtwo" name="listtwo" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" align="right"  class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count ui-first-child" ><?php echo $row['date']; ?><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a></li> 
                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" ><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a class="ui-link-inherit"><p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['time']; ?></strong></p>                       
                    <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['title']; ?></strong></p>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>

                </a></li>
```

Comment: You want `$row['title']` and `$row['text'];` in same line ?

Comment: no, the two buttons with no text in one line with <?php echo $row['date']; ?>

Comment: Why not `<p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['title']; ?><?php echo $row['text']; ?></strong></p>` ?

Comment: You have 2 missing `div`s and do not have block elements in an inline element!

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I want not the rows title and text into one line I want the two icon button into the header line ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of using `span` tags to align them one after the other. I have added 2 of the missing `div`s as well! Take a look at the modified code.

```
<li id ="listtwo" name="listtwo" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" align="right"  class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count ui-first-child" >
    Today
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a>
</li> 
<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" >
    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
        <div class="ui-btn-text">
            <a class="ui-link-inherit">
                <p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc">
                    <span><strong>Time</strong></span>
                    <span><strong>Title</strong></span>
                    <span>Text</span>
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Use a bit of `CSS` to style them accordingly!

Comment: the time title and text shouldnt become edit in my code, only the both <a</a> elements in the first <li

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _shouldnt become edit in my code_!

Comment: time title and text should be how I made it ;)

Comment: Still not very useful!